# Can I use asana API to invite team member via out web app?

Tags: asana, asana-api

Can I use asana API to invite team member via out web app?

For example, if I have users email, is it possible to use your API and create a tool that can invite this user to asana?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Asana API to invite a user via email using the `/workspaces/workspace-id/addUser` endpoint.  The request requires two parameters:  workspace and user.  The user can be referenced by their email address (or their globally unique user ID).

Here is the documentation: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/workspaces#user-mgmt